eliminate circular lambda production in grammar
for all non-empty string, Consider production: 
$S \to SS$ 
$S \to aSb$ 
$S \to bSa$ 
$S \to \lambda$
Replacing last $\lambda$ production, for first production,
$S \Rightarrow SS \Rightarrow \lambda S~\text{or}~S \lambda$, and $S \Rightarrow SS \Rightarrow \lambda \lambda$. Then get: 
$S \to SS~|~S~|~\lambda$ 
$S \to aSb~|~ab$ 
$S \to bSa~|~ba$
But then, no matter how many time we replace $\lambda$ production, we still get one $S \to \lambda$ from $S \to S$.
And I was given the answer: 
$S \to SS$
$S \to aSb~|~ab$
$S \to bSa~|~ba$
It seems to break down to case where string (i) empty or (ii) non-empty. But I dont know how to make this process concrete.
Answer from similar question is great, but it seems didn't consider this "circular" case. So, is there any systematic way to do that, or just guessing?
